# Linear algebra Reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Im looking for a book that would take someone whos completed an introductory course in linear algebra to the needed level of understanding in the subject for an undergraduate at graduation (or pair, triplicate etc of books to get there) preferably with lots of examples or questions with answers.

Comment: For most people whose main focus is math, I would recommend a book that combines abstract and linear algebra, because there is a lot of interplay between the two of them, and a lot will be missed if they are studied separately, neither assuming knowledge of the other. Artin's *Algebra* is good for this. So is Godement's *Algebra*. If you want linear algebra alone, then Halmos's *Finite-dimensional vector spaces*, Gelfand's *Lectures on Linear Algebra* and Kostrikin and Manin's *Linear Algebra and Geometry* are all good choices.

Comment: Golub, Roman, Insel Spence and Friedberg, Hoffman and Kunze, Weintraub,...

Comment: i have taken a couple abstract algebra classes im not against this approach of doing both subjects

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.math.columbia.edu/programs-math/graduate-program/what-graduate-students-are-assumed-to-know/

Comment: that link is ftw tyvm

Answer (score 0):

**This is so late, but it may be usefull for someone!**

One of the best books I have seen in Linear ALgebra for people who have already itroduced to the topic is **Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra** by V. V. Prasolov